# Unable to type in Putty after a few minutes of inactivity?

Tags: linux, command-line, putty

For some reason I am unable to type in Putty when connecting to a remote CentOS server, after a few minutes of inactivity. It appears the prompt is disabled and can't be clicked or typed on. I searched the settings but can't seem to find anything relating to this. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: @JakeGould Is there a setting in the remote host regarding this? I have admin access in the remote host which is CentOS.

Comment: It's very likely that your TCP connection is a bit shaky.  Does it disconnect 30 seconds or so later?  Or does it appear to remain connected, and you just don't see any text?

Comment: You might try useing the 'keepalive' option in putty (settings->Connection, set to something > 0). This will cause putty to send empty packets on a regular basis. If the connection goes bad, the keepalive packets will cause the failed connection to be noticed faster.